# Why am I getting a null?

Tags: java

Why is it when I call `System.out.println(classroom.toStringLong())` I get: classroom: a large lecture hall with a null that goes null to null?

The correct output is supposed to be:  classroom: a large lecture hall with a door that goes outside to sidewalk

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Space classroom = new Space();
         classroom.setName("classroom");
         classroom.setDescription("a large lecture hall");
         Space sidewalk = new Space();
         sidewalk.setName("sidewalk");
         sidewalk.setDescription("a plain concrete sidewalk with weeds growing through the cracks");
         Portal door = new Portal();
         door.setName("door");
         door.setDirection("outside");
         door.setDestination(sidewalk);
         classroom.setPortal(door);
         System.out.println(classroom.toStringLong());
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Space {
  private String _name;
  private String _description;
  private Portal _portal;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
  public String getName() {
    return _name;
  }

  public void setName(String _name){
    this._name=_name;
  }
  public String getDescription() {
    return _description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String _description){
    this._description=_description;
  }
  public Portal getPortal() {
    return _portal;
  }

  public void setPortal(Portal _portal){
    this._portal=_portal;
  }
  public String toString(){
    return _name;
  }
  public String toStringLong(){
    if (_portal!= null){
      Portal p= new Portal();
      p.toStringLong();
      String Longcombined=_name + ": " + _description+" with a "+p.toStringLong();
      return Longcombined;
    }
    else{
      String Long=_name + ": " + _description;
      return Long;
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
public class Portal {
  private String _name;
  private String _direction;
  private Space _destination;

  public String getName() {
    return _name;
  }

  public void setName(String _name){
    this._name=_name;
  }
  public String getDirection(){
    return _direction;
  }
  public void setDirection(String _direction){
    this._direction=_direction;
  }
  public Space getDestination(){
    return _destination;
  }
  public void setDestination(Space _destination){
    this._destination=_destination;
  }
  public String toString(){
    String combined=_name+ " that goes "+_direction;
    return combined;
  }
  public String toStringLong(){
    Space space=new Space();
    String combined=toString() + " to " + space.getDescription() ;
    return combined;
  }

}
```

Comment: This could be *easily* solved with the most basic debugging skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new object of space and printing its description which is null 
rewrite your toStringLong() method to

```
In class Space

public String toStringLong(){
if (_portal!= null)
{
// comment this Portal p= new Portal();
_portal.toStringLong();
String Longcombined=_name + ": " + _description+" with a "+_portal.toStringLong();
return Longcombined;
}
else
{
String Long=_name + ": " + _description;
return Long;
}
}


Class Portal ->

public String toStringLong()
{
String combined=toString() + " to " + _destination.getDescription() ;
return combined;
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: there are toStringLong() in the code?

Comment: where is my +1 ? lol

Answer (score 0):

When run the this code "Space space=new Space();" inside of the toStringLogn() method, new space object is created and also all instant variables of this object are initialized with their default values. Default value of the String is "null". That is why you get null value when you use this object.

It is better to redefine your toStringLong() as follows,

String combined=toString() + " to " + _destination.getDescription() ; 
return combined;